# Unix grep command

Tags: unix

I have an utility script, that displays an information about deployed java app. Here is an example output of this script:

> Name: TestAPP
>
> Version     : SNAPSHOT
>
> Type        : ear, ejb, webservices, web
>
> Source path : /G/bin/app/TESTAPP_LIVE_1.1.9.1.1.ear
>
> Status      : enabled

Is it possible to grep Version and source path values using grep command? Right now im able to do this using following command:

> | grep Version

But it outputs the whole string (e.g. Version: Snapshot) when i am need only a values (e.g Snapshot to use in further script commands)

Comment: grep Version | cut -d ':' -f 2

Comment: posted as answer please like if it works

Comment: You can also use `awk`: `|grep Version|awk '{$print $3}'` (I'm using `$3` and not `$2` because there is a space between ':' and the other words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep Version | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure `grep` solution.

Use the `-P` option for regex mode, and `-o` option for retrieving only what is matching.

```
grep -Po "(?<=^Version : ).*"
```

Here is what you would do for Source:

```
grep -Po "(?<=^Source : ).*"
```

It uses a postive lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `awk` if you're interested:

```
grep Version | awk '{print $3}'
```

`$3` means to print the third word from that line.

Note that:

1. This displays one word only
2. This assumes you have spaces between the colon (and therefore the version is actually the *third* "word"). If you don't, use `$2` instead.